# I can't open ride.py correctly, which is started with Pycharm

Tags: selenium, pycharm

I get all set tools of selenium, such as wxPython, python, also set the 'Path', but when I try to open ride.py to launch selenium, I find this .py started with Pycharm, then only thing I see is the IDE. Do I need to uninstall Pycharm to resolve the problem?
Version -- Pycharm4.5.3, python2.7

Comment: I guess you are double clicking the file which opens it in IDE? If yes the open a terminal and use `python ride.py` to run it

Comment: Yes it works！This problem confused me long time, thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are double clicking the file which opens it in IDE? If yes the open a terminal and use `python ride.py` to run it